# Convert String to Datetime C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string value which is a datetime : "20100825161500" and I want to convert this to a System Datetime. I have tried Convert.ToDateTime and DateTime.Parse and these do not work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to pass the format you need.

Here is an example:

`var parsed = DateTime.ParseExact("20100825161500","yyyyMMddHHmmss", null);`

Possible format values are listed at
[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use something like this

Datetime D = DateTime.ParseExact("20100825161500","yyyymmdd...",null)

here you have a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/String2DateTime.aspx) about how to make you "format" string

Answer (score -2):

Because this string hasn't a format recognized by these 2 functions.

DateTime.Parse and Convert.ToDateTime require your string to be correctly formatted : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx

You will have to write your custom parser for this kind of conversion

Comment: -1: DateTime.ParseExact allows a format to be specified, you don't need to write this yourself.

Comment: I didn't know ParseExact. Thanks for the info