# C# String to DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

```
DateTime frm_datestart = DateTime.Parse(dateStart.Text);
```

This line throws the error:

> Exception Details:
>   System.FormatException: String was not
>   recognized as a valid DateTime.

Where the entered string is from Jquery-UI, examples:

```
 09/29/2010
 09/30/2010
```

Anyone know what the correct format should be?  I'm suprised this isn't working :S

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188585/convert-string-to-date-in-net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert String to Datetime C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616133/convert-string-to-datetime-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an overloaded version of the `DateTime.Parse()` method which accepts a second [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) parameter.

```
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dti = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
dti.ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dateStart.Text, dti);
```

Answer (score 3):

look for `DateTime.ParseExact` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
val = dateStart.Text.ToString("yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: That will probably not even compile (there is no `ToString` override for `String` that takes a `String` as parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) to specify format like this: `DateTime.Parse("dd/MM/yyyy", dateStart.Text, null)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with DateTime.ParseExact() method suggested in previous answers is, it fails on some Cultures. So your application may fail to run correctly on certain Operating Systems.

If you are sure that dateStart.Text will always be in the same format (i.e. en-US), you may try passing appropriate CultureInfo as a second argument. For format "MM/dd/yyyy" use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.