# how to convert a string of date time to customized datetime

Tags: c#

any can help me to convert datetime to customized datetime. in c #

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert String to Datetime C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616133/convert-string-to-datetime-c)

Comment: Please paste an example of what format you need if you want a precise answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "customized datetime"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert.ToDateTime(yourstring).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

you can check details in ....... [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Comment: for the details on the format string see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx